# Putting Image View into Collection View Cell causes IBTool to give warning

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode5, autolayout

I'm using Xcode 5.

For some reason I get following warning if I put Image View into Collection View Cell

```
2013-11-20 06:21:39.987 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[1237:303] 
WARNING: 
Reason:     Could not find layout engine view for view's (<UIView: 0x102939b0; frame = (-20 -20; 90 90); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x10288690>>) coordinate space view <UIView: 0x1028aaf0; frame = (0 0; 50 50); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x10298620>; layer = <CALayer: 0x10299730>>. But the canvas coordinateSpaceView is view's superview, so we are assuming the same in the layout engine.
File:       /SourceCache/IBAutolayoutFoundationIOS/IBAutolayoutFoundation-3430/Framework/Classes/Arbitration/IBAutolayoutEngine.m:335
Method:     -[IBAutolayoutEngine layoutFrameForView:inCoordinateSpaceOfView:]
```

These warnings pollute compilation output and sometimes I miss important messages.

How can I get rid of it ?

Here is snippet of my storyboard that causes it:

```
<collectionView opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" restorationIdentifier="zzzzz" minimumZoomScale="0.0" maximumZoomScale="0.0" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="esr-tl-gXA">
    <rect key="frame" x="80" y="104" width="160" height="207"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
    <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="dJb-8s-18M">
        <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
        <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
        <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
        <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
    </collectionViewFlowLayout>
    <cells>
        <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" id="A9w-gO-BzK">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="55Z-yW-7Qm">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    </imageView>
                </subviews>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            </view>
        </collectionViewCell>
    </cells>
</collectionView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've struggled with this issue for a while (getting similar ibtool errors and exceptions), and have tried all of the following:

1. Checked all of the XIB files in which views were reported as having "faulty" relationships. Also analyzed the crash report in console.app as suggested in the ibtool exception information. Nothing was wrong with my layout.
2. Deleted the XIB files containing the UICollectionViewCell and UICollectionView. Then re-created them from scratch in Xcode5.
3. Clean + rebuild.
4. Restarted Xcode, restarted iOS simulator.
5. Deleted Xcode: ~/Applications/Xcode and ~/Library/Developer/Xcode, then reinatalled latest Xcode, and restarted the machine.
6. Migrated the project to Storyboard (i.e. replaced almost all XIB files with a single storyboard. This tool A LOT of work).

Even after migrating to a Storyboard the same error would occasionally pop up, but I then found out that the following resolves it:

1. Reset the iOS simulator (iOS Simulator > Reset content and settings)
2. Clean the Xcode project, then restart Xcode.
3. Restart iOS simulator.

This is an Apple of-course, and I have raised it with them.

Comment: I'm getting the "Could not find layout engine view" warnings as well, but the build is completing with an error in ibtool, I'm assuming the two are related. Cleaning & restarting Xcode doesn't help. Nor does killing the entire DerivedData directory.

Comment: This is an XCode bug and I've raised it on bugreporter.apple.com. It's been closed shortly thereafter by Apple as a duplicate. So they know about this and hopefully will fix it in the next SDK...